# RecyclerView won't clear itself on new search

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on this simple Github user search app:

[image]

Every time I do a new search, instead of having the recyclerview cleared, new search results are simply appended to the end, which is not what I want. I explicitely cleared the search adapter before doing a new search, seems it's incorrect, though.

Some relevant codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                who = query;
                currentPage = 1;
                searchAdapter.clear();
                searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                doSearchUser(query, currentPage);
                //searchAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

**SearchAdapter.java**

```
package com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.R;
import com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<User> fullSearchResult;
    private List<User> filteredSearchResult;
    private List<User> theData;
    private Context ctxt;

    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView github_profile_pic;
        TextView github_login;

       public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            github_profile_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.github_profile_pic);
            github_login  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.github_login);
        }
    }

    public SearchAdapter(Context ctxt, List<User> list) {
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
        theData = list;
    }

    public void clear() {
        int size = theData.size();
        theData.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_item,
                parent, false);
        return new SearchViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = theData.get(position);
        Glide.with(ctxt)
                .load(user.getAvatarUrl())
                .override(200, 200)
                .into(holder.github_profile_pic);
        holder.github_login.setText(user.getLogin());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return theData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return searchFilter;
    }

    private Filter searchFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<User> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(fullSearchResult);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (User item : fullSearchResult) {
                    if (item.getLogin().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredSearchResult.clear();
            filteredSearchResult.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public void updateData(List<User> newList){
        this.theData.clear();
        this.theData.addAll(newList);
    }
}
```

Full code:  https://github.com/anta40/GithubUserSearch

Update:

> While loading more datas, I found this: Cannot call this method in a
>   scroll callback. Scroll callbacks mightbe run during a measure &
>   layout pass where you cannot change theRecyclerView data. Any method
>   call that might change the structureof the RecyclerView or the adapter
>   contents should be postponed tothe next frame

So it the data loading part itself is not correct.

How to fix this?

Comment: Where is this method `doSearchUser(query, currentPage);`

Comment: It's on `MainActivity.java`. You can see it here: https://github.com/anta40/GithubUserSearch/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/divbyzero/app/githubusersearch/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of hints:

**First** the adapter is returning the size of the full list each time, but it should return the size of the filtered list instead; and you need to initialize the filtered list to the original list (`theData`) when there is no filtering performed.

So, change this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return theData.size();
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredSearchResult == null ? 0 : filteredSearchResult.size();
}
```

And initialize the `filteredSearchResult` at the very beginning (at adapter constructor)

```
public SearchAdapter(Context ctxt, List<User> list) {
    this.ctxt = ctxt;
    theData = list;
    filteredSearchResult = list; // <<<<<<<<< here is the change
}
```

**Second**, your `onBindViewHolder()` gets the `user` from the original list (not the filtered list, so it's most probably return wrong data from the unfiltered list); so change it to the filtered list as well.

so replace `theData` with `filteredSearchResult`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user = filteredSearchResult.get(position); // <<<<<<<<< here is the change
    ...
}
```

And whenever you clear/set the original list, change the filtered list

```
public void clear() {
    int size = theData.size();
    theData.clear();
    filteredSearchResult.clear(); // <<<<<<<<< here is the change
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
}


public void updateData(List<User> newList){
    this.theData.clear();
    this.theData.addAll(newList);
    filteredSearchResult.addAll(newList);  // <<<<<<<<< here is the change
}
```